# Macbook Late 2008 - beeping ocassionaly

Tags: macbook

A MacBook Late 2008(Aluminum) is ocassionaly beeping.

Which may be the reason for this? Is the "beep" coming from the motherboard?

Thanks,

Comment: When is it beeping? Right after you turn it on? During normal usage? How often is it beeping? Does it stop when you turn off the system volume?

Comment: The beeping could be a warning of overheating. Does this happen during times of heavy usage? You may want to investigate smcFanControl.

Comment: **slhck** - It beeps during regular use. I will have to check if it stops while having the speakers volume off, but I am under the impression that the sound is internal and not from the speakers.                      **Randolph West** - checking on smcFanControl right away.